# Apply processor with paperclip if condition it's true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a model with [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/) ruby gem. I defined an attached file with 2 processors (`thumbnail` and `watermark`).

The question is if exist the way to apply the watermark processor if condition is `true`. (the idea it's not define new attached_files without watermark processor)

Thanks in advance.

I try using this code, but dosen't works. If the field eid exist process with watermark else if null process only thumbnail

```
:processors => lambda { |a|
                if a.eid.nil?
                        [:thumbnail,:watermark]
                else
                        [:thumbnail]
                end
                },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `processors` option could accept [proc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L188), so you could make your processors depend on instance:

```
:processors => lambda{ |attachment|
   attachment.instance.some_method_to_get_processors_here
},
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the current Paperclip docs, the lambda is called differently for processors than for styles. Styles are passed the attachment:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => lambda { |attachment| { :thumb =>   
    (attachment.instance.boss? ? "300x300>" : "100x100>") } }
end
```

With `attachment.instance` being an instance of your model. But processors are passed the instance itself:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :processors => lambda { |instance| instance.processors }
  attr_accessor :watermark
end
```

This latter example worked for me. I had `User#processors` return an array of processors (but if you just want the default processor, return `[:thumbnail]`, not an empty array).